# how can I visualize such graph If I am only given this formula

Tags: graph-theory, relations

How can visualize it and prove it is the way it should be visualized?

`∃y∀x(xRy)`

Thanks!

Comment: Assuming you're quantifying over the set of vertices and $R$ is the relation "there is an edge from $x$ to $y$", there are a lot of graphs that satisfy this formula

Answer (score 2):

An answer is similar to an answer to your previous [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3103102/how-can-i-visualize-such-graph-and-how-can-i-prove-it-is-the-way). Given a binary relation $R$ on a set $X$, a pair $(X,R)$ is a directed graph with the set $X$ of vertices and the set $R$ of edges. Condition $\exists y \forall x (xRy)$ means that there exists a vertex $y$ of $X$ such that *each* vertex $x\in X$ has an outdoing edge $(x,y)$ to $y$. That is, the graph visualization contains a respective star with the center $y$. If $|X|\le \frak c$ (in particular, $X$ is finite) then this star can be visualized in a plane or in space.